# kibana console with tripple quotes SQL query

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

Kibana recommends using triple quotes for the queries according to documentation: [1](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sql-rest-overview.html)

I try this recommendation and apply to a sample kibana_sample_data_ecommerce:

```
 GET _/sql
    {
      "query" : """SELECT "day_of_week", avg("taxful_total_price") 
                   FROM "kibana_sample_data_ecommerce" 
                   WHERE "customer_id" = '52'
                   GROUP BY "day_of_week"
                """
    }
```

Unfortunatelly, I got:

```
    {
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "invalid_index_name_exception",
        "reason": "Invalid index name [_], must not start with '_', '-', or '+'",
        "index_uuid": "_na_",
        "index": "_"
      }
    ],
    "type": "invalid_index_name_exception",
    "reason": "Invalid index name [_], must not start with '_', '-', or '+'",
    "index_uuid": "_na_",
    "index": "_"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

However, this works perfectly:

```
POST /_sql?format=txt
{
  "query": "SELECT day_of_week, avg(taxful_total_price) FROM kibana_sample_data_ecommerce WHERE customer_id = 52 GROUP BY day_of_week"
  }
```

So, i get:

```
   day_of_week  |avg(taxful_total_price)
---------------+-----------------------
Friday         |97.88760080645162      
Monday         |135.17824074074073     
Saturday       |66.778125              
Sunday         |88.71875               
Thursday       |101.74375              
Tuesday        |76.564453125           
Wednesday      |87.27793560606061
```

How to make it the right way with tripple quotes?

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, your issue is with the `GET` call itself. You have there `GET _/sql`, which looks like a typo. Try with `GET /_sql`.